# Deleting layout pages in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

Just trying to figure out how to delete pages from a layout in QGis 3.0

I have found where to add pages. Maybe there is no function yet for deleting pages?

Comment: Can you explain process you used and add screenshot please

Answer (score 14):

Right-click on the target page and select `Remove Page`:

[image]